# I want an event should be triggered only before refresh, but not on exit/close of browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

The code I have is:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { //before-unload event
    if ("$transaction-receipt").css("display" == 'block') { //check the div display
        return "Do you want to continue"; //return statement
    }
});
```

This is the code I am using, the output I am getting is:

> "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved"  -> stay on page or leave page.

Instead of this message I am getting the message I have given in the return statement, and I don't want this event to be called on close of browser. I need this event to be called only before refreshing the page.

Comment: What the difference? I think if you describe real difference and/or trouble you want to solve, we probably could help you.

Comment: I've been struggling with this at some point.. and then I gave up :).  It can not be done (properly)... See, you could invoke a function on the `keyUp-event` of `F5`, but then you still have the refresh-button of the browser, which you can't access, 'cause it's part of the browser, not the webpage. And the event of refreshing and closing, as I'm confident you already know, is exactly the same: `onBeforeUnload` and `onUnload`. As an extra bonus, not every browser even supports the `onbeforeunload` (and maybe not even `onunload`). If I recall, not even IE this time, but Firefox! Believe that!

Comment: @LeshaOgonkov I want an event to be performed like confirm before refreshing the page. But on exit no event should be called.

Comment: Well, as i know, that exact behaviour is not possible. You can only check that page was refreshed, _after_ actual refresh.

Comment: What you're asking cannot be done reliably, especially cross-browser.

Comment: can you give me any other ideas to achieve, because this is the requirement in my project